# How to make this a nested For Loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested, cube

I made a code wherein I should print the square and cube of the first 10 counting numbers but I used for loops. What I'm looking for is how to print the same output but using nested (for) statement.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("x\tx*x\tx*x*x\t\n");

    for(x=1; x<=10; x++)
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, x*x, x*x*x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need nested for loops for it.

Comment: A nested `for` loop doesn't seem to fit here. What would you have it loop over?

Comment: If you have an exercise of assignment to solve, please copy-paste it (as text) into your questions. In full and complete, including any and all requirements and limitations.

Comment: `for(int j = 0; j < 1; ++j){for(x=1; x<=10; x++){printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", x, x*x, x*x*x);}}`

Comment: Do you want an additional loop for printing `x`, `x*x` and `x*x*x`?

Comment: Linus Did any of the answers help? If we misunderstood the question, please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

With these few items to print, a nested `for` loop seems unecessary, but if you really want one, it could look like this:

```
    for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
        for(int i = 0, X = x; i < 3; ++i, X *= x) {
            printf("%d\t", X);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5ToTTxGz4)

Answer (score -1):

Here I have added the solution of this code along with its output using the nested for loop
[image: code]